# Does such prime $P$ exist?

Tags: number-theory

The equation $(10^{6n+1}-54n-10)($mod P$) = 0$ , find the value of prime P such that there are AT LEAST 3 solutions for n > 0 , whose values of n are all below (P-1)/6. I don't even know how to solve this using W Alpha , but I used this strategy : Find a prime P such that $10^{6n+1}$ (mod P) and $(54n+10)$ (mod P) both give the same residues. But this strategy is very inefficient and wasting times . Could you help me to find such prime P ?. Does such prime P exist?

Comment: Here it is wanted n > 0.

Comment: Is this directly related to the software Mathematica? If not, it might be better suited for another forum.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165489/first-two-n-such-that-1355297-divides106n5-54n-46-for-n0/) question. Please see my answer, substitute m=6n+1, and modify for variable prime p.